# Proper way to use large amount of known constant variables

Tags: c++

The program receives a vector that represents a character.
It then compares the received vector with all the known vectors that represents characters.

I'm not sure how should I use the known vectors.

A few options I thought of:

1) Using global variables:

```
vector<int> charA{1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> charB{5,3,7,1};
...
vector<int> charZ{3,2,5,6,8,9,0}

char getLetter(const vector<int> &input){
    if(compareVec(input,charA) return 'A';
    if(compareVec(input,charB) return 'B';
    ....
    if(compareVec(input,charZ) return 'Z';

}
```

2) Declaring all variables in function:

```
 char getLetter(const vector<int> &input){
        vector<int> charA{1,2,3,4,5};
        vector<int> charB{5,3,7,1};
        ...
        vector<int> charZ{3,2,5,6,8,9,0}

        if(compareVec(input,charA) return 'A';
        if(compareVec(input,charB) return 'B';
        ....
        if(compareVec(input,charZ) return 'Z';

    }
```

3) Passing the variables

```
char getLetter(const vector<int> &input, vector<int> charA,
      vector<int> charB... , vecotr<int> charZ){
        if(compareVec(input,charA) return 'A';
        if(compareVec(input,charB) return 'B';
        ....
        if(compareVec(input,charZ) return 'Z';

    }
```

Comment: How about some kind of hash-table with the vector as a key and the character as the data? At least you won't have to write lot of `compareVec` calls.

Comment: How many are a "large amount"? Are you sure you want to compile the known vectors into the code? Maybe it would be better to read them in from a separate file?

Comment: `vector` are not the best option for static storage duration variables. An array may be more appropriate.

Comment: @JohnnyJohansson arounds 40 vectors containing 100 integers each

Comment: @Oliv actually i use arrays but to simplify the example i changed to vector

Comment: Do you know anything about the numbers in the "vectors that represent characters"? For example, are they all single digit? Is there a maximum number of them?

Comment: @JonathanMee no i do not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like an application for a [perfect hash generator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html) (link to GNU gperf).

To quote the documentation

> gperf is a perfect hash function generator written in C++. It
>   transforms an n element user-specified keyword set W into a perfect
>   hash function F. F uniquely maps keywords in W onto the range 0..k,
>   where k >= n-1. If k = n-1 then F is a minimal perfect hash function.
>   gperf generates a 0..k element static lookup table and a pair of C
>   functions. These functions determine whether a given character string
>   s occurs in W, using at most one probe into the lookup table.

If this is not a suitable solution then I'd recommend using function statics. You want to avoid function locals as this will badly affect performance, and globals will pollute your namespace.

So something like

```
char getLetter(const vector<int> &input){
    static vector<int> charA{1,2,3,4,5};
    static vector<int> charB{5,3,7,1};
```

Comment: sadly this will make the function super ugly, as it will start with 40 or so arrays/vectors.

Comment: @daniel You can always hide the data away in a separate getter function that returns a reference to a vector, or better even, tests against all vectors and returns the matching vector index (if that's all the information needed). The latter option is important for information hiding (the data structure is invisible to user code). The vector definitions proper can be file static or function static (not polluting name spaces and not constructing multiple times is essential, as Paul correctly said).

Comment: @daniel you can put the data in some `data.dat` and then `#include` it in the place where you need it, to have the source free of a wall of data

Comment: `static const`, better yer: `constexpr`.

Comment: @peterchen didn't understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Daniel: I removed that comment, I was mistaken about the things gperf does. (I let the name mislead me ;)) `in_word_set` indeed seems to verify that `input` is one of the known strings, and not a completely different one having the same hash value.

Answer (score 0):

Giving you snippet, I'd go for:

```
char getLetter(const vector<int> &input)
{
    struct 
    {
       char result;
       std::vector<char> data; 
    } const data[]=
    {
       { 'A', {1,2,3,4,5}, },
       { 'B', {5,3,7,1}, },
       ...
    };

    for(auto const & probe : data)
    {
        if (comparevec(input, probe.data))
           return probe.result;
    }

    // input does not match any of the given values
    throw "That's not the input I'm looking for!"; 
}
```

For 40 such pairs, if this is not called in a tight inner loop, the linear search is good enough.

Alternatives:

- use a `std::map<std::vector<char>, char>` to map valid values to results, and turn `compareVec` into a functor suitable as key-comaprison for the map, and initialize it the same way.
- as above, but use a std::unordered_map.
- use gperf, as suggested by @PaulFloyd above

Answer (score 0):

I would start by suggesting that you hash or represent the numbers in their binary collection so that you are not comparing vectors each time as that would prove very costly. That said, your question is about how to make a dictionary, so whether you improve your keys as I suggested or not, I'd prefer the use of a [`map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
map<vector<int>, char, function<bool(const vector<int>&, const vector<int>&)>> dictionary([](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){
    const auto its = mismatch(cbegin(lhs), cend(lhs), cbegin(rhs), cend(rhs));

    return its.second != cend(rhs) && (its.first == cend(lhs) || *its.first < *its.second);
});
```

If possible `dictionary` should be constructed constant with an `initializer_list` containing all mappings and the comparator. If mappings must be looked up before you are guaranteed to have finished all letters then you obviously can't construct constant. Either way this `map` should be a private member of the class responsible for translating strings. Adding and mapping should be public functions of the class.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/EpUoPf)